# discrete mathematics notes possibilities problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways you can put two similar notes in a bag, so on each
>   one there is a password  of 6 letters (abc..z).

I am having trouble with it. My way of thinking:
On the first note: 26^6
On the second note: it is the same thing, but i may have doubles, so i need to divide it by 2. so i am thinking of (26^6)/2

so the answer is 26^6 + (26^6)/2

But i don't think I am right.

Comment: It is unclear what restrictions you mean by "doubles".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the first bag**: There are $6$ possible spaces and a total of $26$ possible letters. So, the number of ways to create a password is $26^6$.

**For the second bag**: There are again $6$ spaces and $26$ letters, so the number of ways are $26^6$.

The total number of ways are thus $26^6 \times 26^6 = 26^{12}$.

But, *in case you want the passwords in the two bags to be different* then, the second bag should not contain the password as that of the first one, so we should reduce it by $1$, that is, the total ways only under this condition for the second bag are $26^6-1$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify whether or not the notes must list 6 *distinct* letters.

You also need to define "similar" when comparing two passwords. Is differing by only one letter sufficient?

Assuming that letters can appear more than once in a given password, which I assume to be the case, given your answer about the first note), then your answer regarding the the first note is correct.

**But** your answer about the second bag should be $26^6 - 1$,  where we must subtract the one password that is *identical* to the password in the first note.

So:  In how many ways you can put two non-identical notes in a bag, so on each one there is a password of 6 letters (abc..z)?

> $$26^6(26^6 -1)$$

Comment: i should add to +26^6, right?

Comment: i should add to +26^6, right? Because that is the number of possibilities they are the same. you calculated the possibilities they are different

Comment: No, you need to multiply $26^6 \times (26^6 - 1)$.  That is, you need to apply the [rule of the product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 1):

There are $((26)^6)^2=26^{12}$ such configurations possible, if no restrictions for certain passwords apply.